# Create KSOAP request with Properties containing Attributes

Tags: android, ksoap2

is there an easy way to create a request with KSOAP2 for Android that contains Properties that themselves contain Attributes, without creating an class that gets serialized?

The Request should contain sth. like

```
<Code>
     <OwnProperty firstAttribute="1stAttr" secondAttribute="2ndAttr"> propertyValue</OwnProperty>
</Code>
```

Any help is appreciated,
Rigoroth

Comment: didn't understand your question. Please explain a little...

Answer (score 0):

SoapObject request = new SoapObject(Namespace,MethodName);
request.addAtribute("name","peter");

i think is these you need sorry i'm late

Comment: Hi, I tried that but you are either able to add properties or attributes to a SoapObject but not Elements that contain both. If I create a SoapObject req with `req.addAttribute("name", "Peter"); req.addAttribute("lastName", "smith"); req.addProperty("Hometown", "York")` I always get sth like `<ObjectName name="Peter" lastName="smith"><Hometown>York</Hometown></ObjectName>`. Problem is that the Property is always in another XML-Element and I cannot add the Property without defining a name for it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think thats possible without implementing KVSeriazable

Comment: How do you do that with kvm Serializeable? can you please add an example of this.